# How do I use many instances of the same event handler with different state?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-event

I have an OTP application with an event that happens periodically. There are several actors that want to do stuff in response to the event. The stuff each actor does is a function of its own state, but otherwise they're identical.

My problem is with how I go about incorporating this setup into a supervision tree. I have a gen_event manager with each actor being an event handler. This would work well if it weren't for the fact that gen_event supervision is weird. Once my first handler is `add_sup_handler`'d the rest fail with `already_started` and my gen_server that's acting as a supervisor for the event handlers dies.

So what should I do here? I'm starting to think I should just write my own event manager that can keep track of all my actors and their state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`gen_event:add_handler/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_event.html#add_handler-3):

> Handler is the name of the callback module `Module` or a tuple
>   `{Module,Id}`, where `Id` is any term. The `{Module,Id}` representation
>   makes it possible to identify a specific event handler when there are
>   several event handlers using the same callback module.